# add with Bootstrap footer in Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I Was working in (http://constantin-entertainment.info/accountant_cms/)this site i just try to 
change this site in responsive Bootstrap.but I can't change the footer in Responsive Bootstrap
pls Help me to changing this footer in responsive bootstrap.pls help me pls.

```
 <tr>
     <td style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;" bgcolor="#E9E9E9">                                 
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
         <tbody><tr><td><a href="" class="spectitle2">Development</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
        </tbody></table>
     </td>
     <td style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;" bgcolor="#E9E9E9">                                 
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
         <tbody><tr><td><a href="" class="spectitle2">Development</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
        </tbody></table>
     </td>
     <td style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;" bgcolor="#E9E9E9">                                 
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
         <tbody><tr><td><a href="" class="spectitle2">Development</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
        </tbody></table>
     </td>
     <td style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;" bgcolor="#E9E9E9">                                 
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
         <tbody><tr><td><a href="" class="spectitle2">Development</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
        </tbody></table>
     </td>
     <td style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;" bgcolor="#E9E9E9">                                 
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
         <tbody><tr><td><a href="" class="spectitle2">Development</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
        </tbody></table>
     </td>
     <td style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;" bgcolor="#E9E9E9">                                 
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
         <tbody><tr><td><a href="" class="spectitle2">Development</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="#" class="sectitle">Webzer</a></td></tr>
        </tbody></table>
     </td>

   </tr>
```

Comment: Just a note: you're website is vulnerable to [**sql injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

You're using table elements ( and ) which are not responsive.

Example of responsive footer: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/